# Use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() and set()* methods on a different user's Google Spreadsheet URL

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google App Script that receives users' spreadsheet urls and attempts to set data to their documents. This process works when I am signed in on my own gmail account and setting entries to my own spreadsheet, but it doesn't work with my other gmail account's spreadsheet url corresponding with the former's App Script.

I know that the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) explicitly states:

```
Spreadsheet:    Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()).
                Cannot open other spreadsheets (SpreadsheetApp.openById() or SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()).
```

But is there some way that I'm unaware of that can potentially circumvent these rules? Can I have users give me read and write access so that I can `set()` data to their provided spreadsheet url? I've added the follow `oauthscope` to my `appmanifest.json` in my App Script:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
```

Comment: If the sheets are not writable by your account, you need to obtain explicit authorization to execute as the requesting user. This would generally be done with the Sheets API and a custom authorization header. You'll want to read about OAuth

Answer (score 0):

So the spreadsheet url just needs to have a sharing permission of "anyone can edit."